# Footer and radial gradient not working on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am working on a school project and we have to build a fake website for a bed and breakfast. Here is the link http://www.bbwillowlake.co.nf/ . If you view the site in Google Chrome it runs fine, but if you view the site in the new IE you can see that the footer over laps the text at the bottom and the radial gradient is not radial it is linear. How can i fix this please veiw the site in the new IE and Chrome so you can see the difference.

Here is the code for the main page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
B & B Willow Lake | Home
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
<h1><a href="index.php"><font color="#FFFFFF">B & B Willow Lake</font></a></h1>
</header>
<ul id="menu">
<li>
<a href="packages.php">Packages</a>
<ul>  
<li><a href="one_and_two_night.php">One and Two Night</a>
</li>
<li><a href="anniversary.php">Anniversary</a>
</li>
<li><a href="extended_stay.php">Extended Stay</a>
</li>
<li><a href="honey_moon.php">Honey Moon</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="activities.php">Activities</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="indoor.php">Indoor</a>
</li>
<li><a href="outdoor.php">Outdoor</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="dine.php">Dine</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="specials.php">Specials</a>
</li>
<li><a href="breakfast.php">BreakFast</a>
</li>
<li><a href="lunch.php">Lunch</a>
</li>
<li><a href="teaparty.php">Tea Party</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="directions.php">Directions</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<section id="section_slide">
<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="background" id="png1"><img src="images/background3.jpg" alt="background2" id="png3"><img src="images/background2.jpg" alt="background3" id="png2"><img src="images/background4.jpg" alt="background4" id="png4">
</section>
<div id="middle_wrapper">
<section id="section">
<article>
<h2>Play</h2>
<a href="play.html"><img src="images/play.jpg" id="png5" alt="background5" id="picmain"></a>
<p>Here will go a text area that talks about all the stuff they can do out door and in door most of the descrpiton will be like the descrpition on the acrives page which it is refing to,<br />
<a id="learnmore" href="play.php">Learn More</a>
</p></article><hr /> 
<article>
<h2>Stay</h2><a href="stay.php"><img src="images/stay.jpg" id="png6" alt="background6" id="picmain2"></a>
<p>This wil be a ref to the package page just a shorter descrpiton so sum up what our stay is like all of these little text areas like play stay dine and cel shoul have a blue text area at the bottom that says learn more that when liked should link to the main page for the subject.<br />
<a id="learnmore2" href="stay.php">Learn More</a>
</p><hr /></article>
<article>
<h2>Dine</h2><a href="dine.php"><img src="images/dine.jpg" id="png7" alt="background7" id="picmain3"></a>
<p>Here will be a desc of the dine page which well tell the user the basics of what eating is like at the resort b and b willow lake it should also tell them that there is a kids menu for there kids and that there is fine dining for the adults and a lot of places to eat for the famlily and just for lovers to get away and eat.<br />
<a id="learnmore3" href="dine.php">Learn More</a>
</p><hr /></article>
<article>
<h2>Celebrate</h2><a href="cel.php"><img src="images/cel.jpg" id="png8" alt="background8" id="picmain4"></a>
<p>This well talk about the events that you can host and the resort like wewdings and birth days tea partys any thing from normal kids birth day partys to highclass wedingns and events of any sort.<br />
<a id="learnmore4" href="celebrate.php">Learn More</a>
</p></article>
</section>
<aside id="aside">
<br />
<br />
<pre>
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Packages">Packages</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="One and Two Night">One and Two Night $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Anniversary">Anniversary $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Extended Stay">Extended Stay $1,000.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Honey Moon">Honey Moon $1,000.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----MIIIQQYJKoZIhvcNAQcEoIIIMjCCCC4CAQExggEwMIIBLAIBADCBlDCBjjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UEAxQIbGl2ZV9hcGkxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXJlQHBheXBhbC5jb20CAQAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYAMs9r2YG9I7ikzCDRIZqc64nR7wAd2EBIWaIKjbAcQUTp4AueD6i7L4t9AWswvItQPT7rK69SZLWJfPwVAPDXm76ceQ+AU+q1BmIhD5aYa3eyPnyXhlsI3729mpCh3Dw0X6pkg1kBWPdtRO4h6OEEZhZ53Vj6pkpSNYag0L5SZZTELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwggG9BgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECJD929txeFAagIIBmIA8gAI8OxJHVsUUrxbf6a+5gqoMJ2QNN9zZwBOnkn2XD9EVCLGoFg2X4y83o7s2AfI1fXggBIq07Gl9f2liBAMJ1SPJCtKrcxnY+ZNNk0ktV5FklNQmXsMHHvn/+okYe5ooSDKxn/O+BGm3P+ReaxdWhKSe4p0lSU2rApjnyhYacLcOiWAqnhKwXzFitUloM8FO1koFBypKkx+laE62z7lbEmVnXVgn2k32vu4HR/akIDfj/Uz/oOYQnDFyP9NcWZiH/cwLfq+wOrVqBv0C64hZH2I2Q8uErbtSPFnmCcAKcNOciDAat926O1SmloHMbkmZHNRgwXv0fIAwlR+5DXRyeVvriJUCaLHZxKOxR93bJ8QE27J5U7jdkS3eZ0jHplCi8ahJRNSwZUPS999ldBPRGS4NGT4cHCZ2+nydhIAbycZOG+IJTWWgq3v758c3iTmPCB3XzZatuQb1K3/BK7srpFIk+anT17XzfyjbVr9Om7ZduFAZQSbOZtsvtdDNRk0q/Nc7rRGSz8BpdlQ9QPObrnOLVhp6zqCCA4cwggODMIIC7KADAgECAgEAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGOMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcTDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxFDASBgNVBAoTC1BheVBhbCBJbmMuMRMwEQYDVQQLFApsaXZlX2NlcnRzMREwDwYDVQQDFAhsaXZlX2FwaTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNcmVAcGF5cGFsLmNvbTAeFw0wNDAyMTMxMDEzMTVaFw0zNTAyMTMxMDEzMTVaMIGOMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcTDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxFDASBgNVBAoTC1BheVBhbCBJbmMuMRMwEQYDVQQLFApsaXZlX2NlcnRzMREwDwYDVQQDFAhsaXZlX2FwaTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNcmVAcGF5cGFsLmNvbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAwUdO3fxEzEtcnI7ZKZL412XvZPugoni7i7D7prCe0AtaHTc97CYgm7NsAtJyxNLixmhLV8pyIEaiHXWAh8fPKW+R017+EmXrr9EaquPmsVvTywAAE1PMNOKqo2kl4Gxiz9zZqIajOm1fZGWcGS0f5JQ2kBqNbvbg2/Za+GJ/qwUCAwEAAaOB7jCB6zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUlp98u8ZvF71ZP1LXChvsENZklGswgbsGA1UdIwSBszCBsIAUlp98u8ZvF71ZP1LXChvsENZklGuhgZSkgZEwgY4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIGA1UEChMLUGF5UGFsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsUCmxpdmVfY2VydHMxETAPBgNVBAMUCGxpdmVfYXBpMRwwGgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg1yZUBwYXlwYWwuY29tggEAMAwGA1UdEwQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAgV86VpqAWuXvX6Oro4qJ1tYVIT5DgWpE692Ag422H7yRIr/9j/iKG4Thia/Oflx4TdL+IFJBAyPK9v6zZNZtBgPBynXb048hsP16l2vi0k5Q2JKiPDsEfBhGI+HnxLXEaUWAcVfCsQFvd2A1sxRr67ip5y2wwBelUecP3AjJ+YcxggGaMIIBlgIBATCBlDCBjjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UEAxQIbGl2ZV9hcGkxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXJlQHBheXBhbC5jb20CAQAwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTEzMTIwNjE2MjA0NlowIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFErtGk2xl99fwZ24pPz27NZpLG8tMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIGAQEb9dpBzufCv6Pbrj+PPl92ejRaBVMVJg0Xymz1sWhbP06l4Odc35NDgKse5NZ1ynxBVRstgadAstk8xAY/notAT1L5xPl7KOjVFDe3O4T0fPenM0GnoJqkI2p24zYDY9TrF8S8Xs21hnjqzDUZH2LcFoIHBjLhYSIAJcRRAEBQ=-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

<br />
<br />
<br />
</pre>
<h2>Why Us?</h2>
<p>
<pre>
adsfsdafasdfadfsdafasfsdafasdfa<br />dfsdafadfdddddddujhyjbddddddd<br />dddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />
asdfasdfsdafadsdfasdfdsfadsfasdfa<br />dfadsfasdfadfda<br />sfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdafsdafdsafd<br />
dsasdfdsfsdfasdfasdfdfddddddddddddd<br />ddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />dddddddddddd<br />
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />Sddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br />ddddddddddddddd<br />
</pre>
</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<iframe title="Youtube video player" width="90%" height="390px" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI6aVSzZsps&list=TLctir32a34lOmJXkxNcviVk5lubS_IL3N"></iframe><br />
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="images/facebook.gif" alt="facebook" id="facebook"></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="images/twitter.gif" alt="twitter" id="twitter"></a><a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="images/g+.gif" alt="g+" id="google"></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><img src="images/youtube.gif" alt="youtube" id="youtube"><br /></a>
</aside>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
<h1><a href="index.php"><font color="#FFFFFF">B & B Willow Lake</font></a></h1>
<p>
bandbwillowlake@gmail.com
</p>
<p>
</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the style.css

```
*{
font-family:Verdana;
}
body {  
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* Safari */
background: -o-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: radial-gradient(#D8D8D8, #A4A4A4, #6E6E6E); /* Standard syntax */
}
pre {
    overflow-x: auto; /* Use horizontal scroller if needed */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space : normal;
}  
#header{
color: #FFF;
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}
#facebook{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#twitter{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#google{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#youtube{
width:50px;
height:50PX;
margin-left:5px;
}
#picmain{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain2{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain3{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
#picmain4{
text-align:center;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}

h1{
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
text-decoration:none;
}
h1 a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
}
h2{
color: #000;
margin-bottom:8px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
#nav{
background-color: #254159;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
a:link{
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
#section_slide{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
img{
}
#section{
background-color: #FFF;
}
#png1{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png2{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png3{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png4{
width:25%;
height:150px;
}
#png5{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png5:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#png6{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#button{
width:auto;
height:25px;
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
color:#FFF;
}
#png6:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
img{
border: none;
}
hr{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
height: 1px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;  
}
#png7{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png7:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#png8{
width:150px;
height:150px;
transition:width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
}
#png8:hover{
width:250px;
height:250px;
transform:rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); /* Safari */
}
#aside{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}
#footer{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#menu{
width: 82%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
list-style: none;  
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}

#menu li{
float: left;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
position: relative;
}

#menu a{
float: left;
height: 25px;
padding: 0 25px;
color: #999;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a{
color: #FFF;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;    
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;    
background: #FFFFFF;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
}

#menu ul li{
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;  
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child{   
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a{    
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */   
height: 10px;
width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */    
height: 10px;
width: 150px;
}

.button{
background-color:red;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
background: #111;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #5882FA),color-stop(1, #3D72A4));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
background: linear-gradient(#5882FA, #3D72A4);
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: -8px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}

#learnmore{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore2{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore3{
color: blue;
}

#learnmore4{
color: blue;
}
* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Here is the layout css page.

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper{
width: 82%;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#header{
width: 82%;
height: 75px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#nav{
width: 82%;
height: 32px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#section_slide{
width: 82%;
height: 150px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#middle_wrapper{
width: 82%;
height:auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#section{
width: 56%;
height:auto;
padding: 2%;
float: left;
margin-bottom:150px;
}
#aside{
width: 36%;
height:auto;
padding: 2%;
float: left;
}
#footer{
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
clear: both;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you testing? IE8/9 did not support CSS gradients. IE10/11 apparently do support them. For IE9, you can use an SVG background image instead.

Comment: Your radial gradient is radial, not linear in IE10 as well. The problem is that your body has a height of only 302px, so it then gets repeated horizontally (which doesn't happen in Chrome for some reason). I don't know why the body has that height, there's just a lot of code to go through. Do you know how to make a reduced test case?

Comment: Ah, it's the floats inside `#wrapper` - you just need to add `overflow: hidden` on the `#wrapper` element and this solves both problems.

Answer (score 2):

This actually appears to be an issue with floated html elements. Your `<div id="wrapper">` contains elements that are `float: left;`. When you `float` an element, its parent does not automatically expand to contain any floated children. To do that, you need to `clear` the floated elements.

Have a read of http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, which explains the theory behind floats, and how to clear them in a lot more detail.

Additionally, IE8 and 9 did not support CSS gradients. IE10 and 11 do support them. For IE9, you can use an SVG background image instead.

Comment: So I need to and a clear: both; in all the divs with float: left;

Comment: Nearly :) You'd either need a `<div>` with `clear: both;` *after* the floated divs, or one of the other methods in the "Techniques for Clearing Floats" section of the linked article. The overflow method is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I would try out css3pie, it is CSS 3 Progressive Internet Explorer, a plugin that will help IE to render CSS3. http://css3pie.com/